# Can't activate deep link in Android using react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-router-flux

I implemented deep link in React Native in reference to https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/2148 .

This works all right in iOS. (`xcrun simctl openurl booted "my-app://"`)
But it doesn't work in Android. (`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my-app://my-app"`)

It says

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=my-app://my-app pkg=com.my-app }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=my-app://my-app flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.my-app }
```

I think EITHER the way I activate the link(`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my-app://my-app"`) OR the code in https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/2148 is wrong.

Does anyone know the way to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing package name in the end of your shell command (com.my-app or whatever it is).